# Optimizing rolling Pearson correlation

Tags: python, pandas, pearsons-correlation-coefficient

I have Pandas DataFrame with multiple columns (3000 or more) with timeseries in them (I have dates as indecies).

```
            |id1    id2     id3  
-------------------------------
2021-01-06  | 27    29      5
2021-01-07  | 24    20      9   ...
2021-01-08  | 21    13      14
2021-01-09  | 10    6       24
                ...
```

And I need to do rolling window computations of Pearson correlation on each pair of columns. I'm using multiprocessing and regular `pandas.DataFrame.corr()` function and it take days to complete the calculation. Is it possible to speed up that process without doing cloud computations?

Comment: You are doing every combination of 2 columns, from 3000, so 5 million calls to `corr()`, for each window? How big are your windows, and do they advance one row at a time, or a bigger step.  (It doesn't really matter, but I was thinking the bigger the window, and the smaller the step, the more likely an incremental update algorithm is worthwhile.)